# How do I Performance test a 3rd party API which has limitations on number of concurrent users?

Tags: jmeter, mocking, performance-testing, load-testing, web-api-testing

I am new to Performance testing.
I want to Performance test my application that calls a 3rd party API (Transunion) for 2000 concurrent users using JMeter. The 3rd party API Transunion has limitation of up to 5 concurrent users maximum at a time.

How should I do Performance testing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You should not be testing the 3rd-party API as this is not something you can efficiently control and even if you discover that it doesn't support 5 users but supports 1 - there is not much you will be able to do about it.

Your load test should focus solely on your application and your domain, all external stuff like banners, images, maps, videos, 3rd-party integrations should be [excluded](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732519-Excluding-Domains-from-the-Load-Test).

If the 3rd-party API is an integral part of your application you can use a [Mock Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) pattern to not to make the real call to the 3rd-party API but rather return a "dummy" response. If you cannot implement mocking in your application code you can use an external program like [WireMock](http://wiremock.org/) or [HTTP API Mock](https://github.com/vtrifonov/http-api-mock) or similar.

But be aware that the **whole integrated system acts at the speed of its slowest component** so if this 3rd-party integration is the essential part of your application - I don't see a lot of sense in performing the load test apart from concurrency testing like "what happens if from 2 to 5 users will do X at the same moment"

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic Use Case for API simulations / remote mocks. They act as stand-ins for the real 3rd-party API dependencies that may be unavailable, impose rate limits/throttle calls, charge per transaction, etc. and they can also simulate slowness in such APIs, inject faults, and more to help with end-to-end integration or performance testing.

There is a choice of tools out there with different capabilities; you can write your own, too.

*Disclaimer: I am involved with one such tool so I'll refrain from providing tool recommendations* :-)